# Opencv two camera source

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with opencv and have two video source. I am using the following code. The code works sometimes and sometimes it does not work.  Is there a problem with my code. How can I make the amends...

```
import cv2

Channel0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
IsOpen0, Image0 = Channel0.read()
Channel1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
IsOpen1, Image1 = Channel1.read()

while IsOpen0 and IsOpen1:
    IsOpen0, Image0 = Channel0.read()
    IsOpen1, Image1 = Channel1.read()
    cv2.imshow("Webcamera",Image0)
    cv2.imshow("Panasonic",Image1)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

PS It always works when I use only one video source.

Comment: Could you explain what it does when it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out my error. For some reason the following code works. It must have been problem with  threading...

```
import thread
import time
import cv2


def Webcamera(): 
    Channel0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    IsOpen0, Image0 = Channel0.read()
    while IsOpen0:
        IsOpen0, Image0 = Channel0.read()
        cv2.imshow("Webcamera",Image0)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    if not IsOpen0:
        time.delay(0.5)
        print "Error opening Web camera"


def Panasonic():
    Channel1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    IsOpen1, Image1 = Channel1.read()
    while IsOpen1:
        IsOpen1, Image1 = Channel1.read()
        cv2.imshow("Panasonic",Image1)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    if not IsOpen1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Error opening Panasonic"

try:
   thread.start_new_thread(Webcamera,())
   thread.start_new_thread(Panasonic,())
except:
   print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
   pass
```